# SUM rows of MULTIPLY columns

Tags: google-sheets

I need a cell which resume :

`A1*B1 + A2*B2` etc ... automatically, without adding line by line as `=SUM(A1*B1 + A2*B2)`

[image]

`= 25*7.5 + 0*10.5 = 187.5`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try:

`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A2,B1:B2)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be dynamic such that every time you add a new row, the sum will be updated then I think you need to do it manually.

[image]

```
# Cell C2
= A1*A2
```

Drag this formula to the entire column of C so that every time new values are inserted, the corresponding cell in column C will be updated. As for `Cell F`

```
# Cell F
= SUM(C2:C)
```

This will take the sum of the entire column C if a cell contains a value.

[EDIT]

Much better solution is you could use `SUMPRODUCT`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A, B2:B)
```

[image]

This will give you the same effect as the first solution that I have mentioned and it is already dynamic so every time new values in a row, your sum will be updated!

NOTE: The syntax of performing operations that extends in the entire column is only supported in google spreadsheets (as far as I know) and not in Microsoft Excel.